# shell script for showing processes at a specific date

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

So I've been trying to write a shell script that shows background processes at a specific date. Here is the problem:: the date is a parameter given by the user. I read the date and validated it, but i don't know what command to use. Also, i tried using ps command but to no success. I do not know if my date format is ok either. Here is what I did:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Date dd-mm-yyyy"
read date
if [[ $date =~ ^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$ ]]
then echo "Date is valid"
else echo "Date is not valid"
fi
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If I understand your question (Q) correctly, there is no source of process information that can be used to "query" by date. There may be a process-created date, but you won't be able to tell how much CPU (or anything else) it was using, except at the current time. I think you're talking about a process history, and the only way to do that in scripting is to save history files. Maybe `while sleep 5 mins ; do ps axuw > /path/to/process/hist/$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M) ; done` will generate the data you need, but it will be a real slog to use it. ....

Comment: There may be add-on packages for your OS that will do system logging with the details you need, but will likely require research, learning etc. If you're trying to track down a "valid" process that is causing problems for the rest of your system, the `while` loop may be your fastest approach to getting any results, but again, it will be slog. You'll need to adjust expectations. Good luck.

Comment: Your  date spec `dd-mm-yyyy` is valid of course, but most logging utilities use the naturally sorting `yyyy-mm-dd` format. If your `if [[ $date ...` code isn't working, and that is real meat of your Q, then use `set -x` to see what values are acutally being substituted for your variables. `set +x` turns that feature off. Good luck.

Comment: AND it never hurts to run your code thru https://shellcheck.net. Be sure to include `#!/bin/bash` or whatever shell you are using as the first line of your code when you submit it ther.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your question you are trying to validate date format in a shell script, so you have to check form of the input using the regex as below :

```
#! /bin/bash

isDateInvalid()
{
    DATE="${1}"

    # Autorized separator char ['space', '/', '.', '_', '-']
    SEPAR="([ \/._-])?"

    # Date format day[01..31], month[01,03,05,07,08,10,12], year[1900..2099]
    DATE_1="((([123][0]|[012][1-9])|3[1])${SEPAR}(0[13578]|1[02])${SEPAR}(19|20)[0-9][0-9])"

    # Date format day[01..30], month[04,06,09,11], year[1900..2099]
    DATE_2="(([123][0]|[012][1-9])${SEPAR}(0[469]|11)${SEPAR}(19|20)[0-9][0-9])"

    # Date format day[01..28], month[02], year[1900..2099]
    DATE_3="(([12][0]|[01][1-9]|2[1-8])${SEPAR}02${SEPAR}(19|20)[0-9][0-9])"

    # Date format day[29], month[02], year[1904..2096]
    DATE_4="(29${SEPAR}02${SEPAR}(19|20(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])))"

    # Match the date in the Regex

    if ! [[ "${DATE}" =~ "^(${DATE_1}|${DATE_2}|${DATE_3}|${DATE_4})$" ]]
    then
        echo -e "ERROR - '${DATE}' invalid!"
    else
        echo "${DATE} is valid"
    fi
}

echo
echo "Exp 1: "`isDateInvalid '12/13/3000'`
echo "Exp 2: "`isDateInvalid '12/11/2014'`
echo "Exp 3: "`isDateInvalid '12 01 2020'`
echo "Exp 4: "`isDateInvalid '28-02-2014'`
echo "Exp 5: "`isDateInvalid '12_02_2002'` 
echo "Exp 6: "`isDateInvalid '12.10.2099'`
echo "Exp 7: "`isDateInvalid '31/11/2001'`
```